# Call to undefined function cur_init()

Tags: php, curl

I've seen plenty of these both here on stackoverflow and in other places - by try as I might i am still getting this error.

Any way - useful information

The Code I am trying to execute is as follows

```
<?php   

    function getOAuthToken ( $grantCode, $grant_type ) {
        global $client_id;
        global $client_secret;
        global $refresh_token;


        try {     
            ini_set('display_errors', '1');
            error_reporting(E_ALL);

            $oauth2token_uri = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
            $clienttoken_post = array(
                "client_id" => $client_id,
                "client_secret" => $client_secret
                );

            if ($grant_type === "online") {
                $clienttoken_post["code"] = $grantCode;
                $clienttoken_post["redirect_uri"] = $refresh_token;
                $clienttoken_post["grant_type"] = "authorization_code";
            }

            if ($grant_type == "offline") {
                $clienttoken_post["refresh_token"] = $grantCode;
                $clienttoken_post["grant_type"] = "refresh_token";
            }        

            $curl = cur_init($oauth2token_uri);

        }
        catch ( Exception $e ) 
        {
            echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
        }


    };

    session_start();

    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {    
        try 
        {

            $accessToken = getOAuthToken($_GET['code'],'online');            

        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
        }
    }  

?>
```

Windows 7 (64bit) IIS Express

PHP.INI

executing phpInfo() gives the following information.

Php Version 5.3.24

Loaded Configuration File   C:\Program Files (x86)\php\php.ini

cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.29.0
Age 3
Features
AsynchDNS   Yes
Debug   No
GSS-Negotiate   Yes
IDN No
IPv6    Yes
Largefile   Yes
NTLM    Yes
SPNEGO  Yes
SSL Yes
SSPI    Yes
krb4    No
libz    Yes
CharConv    No
Protocols   dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host    i386-pc-win32
SSL Version OpenSSL/0.9.8y
ZLib Version    1.2.7
libSSH Version  libssh2/1.4.2

Executing the following code;

```
<?php

 $ci=@curl_version(); $cv=$ci["version_number"]; if($cv) echo "curl
 installed"; else echo "curl is not installed";

?>
```

Shows curl installed

Libcurl.dll (v7.13) installed in Windows\System32 C:\Windows\SysWOW64

Extensions directory is given as C:\Program Files (x86)\php\v5.3\ext

this contains php_curl.dll (ver 5.3.24)

in the php.ini file the line

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

has no semi-colon in front of it

The DLL ssleay32.dll (ver 0.9.8y) has been copied into c:\windows\System32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64

the DLL libeay32.dll (ver 1.0.1e) has been copied into c:\windows\System32 and c:\windows\sysWOW64

Which I think covers all the answers I have been able to find but still have the  ' Call to undefined function cur_init() ' error and have no idea what to try next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

should be

```
$curl = curl_init($oauth2token_uri);
```

and not

```
$curl = cur_init($oauth2token_uri);
```